# Como disparar uma função depois de uma determinada data e hora

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um script que dispare uma certa função depois que uma data e hora tenha passado. Já tentei de todas as formas mais não consigo, sempre da algum erro ou bug. Meu último teste fiz assim:

```
var time = '08/03/2014 23:45';
setInterval(function() {
    if ( Date(time) <= Date() ) {
        document.body.innerHTML += 'Ring ring! ♪♫ <br>';
    }
}, 1000);
```

Não há problema se a função for disparada sempre que a hora tiver passado e o valor de *time* deve ser igual ao exemplo.

Comment: Esse formato de data é `mm/dd/yy` ou `dd/mm/yy`? Até onde eu saiba, o construtor de `Date` recebe o parâmetro no primeiro formato.

Comment: Era isso que eu estava errando, mais já consegui aqui

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Da maneira que você escreveu melhor seria comparar valores numéricos:

```
// Pega o valor numérico da data e hora:
var time = (new Date('08/03/2014 23:45')).getTime();
setInterval(function() {
  // Compara com o valor atual:
  if (time <= Date.now()) {
    document.body.innerHTML += 'Ring ring! ♪♫ <br>';
  }
}, 1000);
```

Mas você também poderia escrever de forma mais otimizada, como:

```
// Pega o valor numérico da data e hora:
var time = (new Date('08/03/2014 23:45')).getTime();
// Executa a função quando no tempo marcado:
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.innerHTML += 'Ring ring! ♪♫ <br>';
}, time - Date.now());
```

O que ficaria mais simples e mais rápido, uma vez que só executaria a função na hora certa.

Comment: Aqui não deu certo =/

Comment: ha pronto, deu certo agora o/